# Save dictionaries in Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, core-data

I have a JSON with this format:

```
     {
        features =     (
                    {
                data =             (
                                    {
                        key = 1;
                        val = “Normal  ";
                    },
                                    {
                        key = 2;
                        val = “Regular”;              
                    
                    }
                );
                desc = Prods;
                lang = en;
                type = 1;
            },
                    {
                data =             (
                                    {
                                                        {
                        key = 1;
                        val = “Gas”;
                    },
                                    {
                        key = 2;
                        val = “Water”;
                    }
                );
                desc = Servs;
                lang = es;
                type = 2;
            }
```

What I need to do is to save this info into two dictionaries (one for type 1 and the other with type 2) in core-data and load this information in another class, how could I do that?

Comment: Hi Simojo!
Can you tell us more about what did you try and what is not working for you?
Otherwise you can look into the documentation of core data its pretty detailed.

Comment: This is not JSON and it's unclear what *one for type 1* means.

Comment: First, You dont need coredata to pass data between two classes/ViewControllers, Coredata makes sense only if you need persistent storage not otherwise, Second, you dont save JSON to coredata, Coredata is an object oriented wrapper over sqlite (at least in its most simplest form, you can obviously change persistent store of your coredata stack, but I assume you are a newbie so dont worry about that), so you save core data entity to managedObject context which ultimately gets saved in sqlite as row (entry) in  table. With all these info rethink what you need, read tutorial on coredata

Comment: My guess, from the minimal info you have provided in your question 1. You dont need core data 2. You dont have much of idea on coredata so read a tutorials on it to see it in working and then decide do you really need it, raywenderlich has multiple articles on this topic